# Some text lost while reading audio

Tags: python, audio, video

I would like to extract all text from video. I have downloaded a video and applied the following code:

```
from transformers import pipeline
sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
import moviepy.editor as mp
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
clip =mp.VideoFileClip("Test_Video.mp4")
clip.audio.write_audiofile("Video.wav")
with sr.AudioFile("Video.wav") as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    # data = r.record(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(text)
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
MoviePy - Writing audio in Video.wav
MoviePy - Done.
what's the weather really why I'm interested I was just trying to be agreeable Honey's guy he didn't know what he wanted so he's fooling around and she catches him at it and like one girlfriend isn't enough room so you're a one girl guy that's right right looking for a right now actually got the new job trying to get this apartment anyway so you're a duck is everyone's a doctor around here this apartment building everyone's a green slippers green pyjamas the game waiting for the vacate doctor what kind of doctor I'm a resident internal medicine so if I needed a doctor you could be it I could be her yeah I could I'm working at the hospital remind me saying that oh yeah of course I have some patience coming and so I should probably work I still like that another cup of coffee
```

When I listen to the audio file or the original video file, it is obvious that some text is lost, maybe because of quiet talk, and for some reason, not all text is recordable.

I tried the following code, dividing a wav into chunks:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

# create a speech recognition object
r = sr.Recognizer()

# a function that splits the audio file into chunks
# and applies speech recognition
def get_large_audio_transcription(path):
    """
    Splitting the large audio file into chunks
    and apply speech recognition on each of these chunks
    """
    # open the audio file using pydub
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)
    # split audio sound where silence is 700 miliseconds or more and get chunks
    chunks = split_on_silence(sound,
        # experiment with this value for your target audio file
        min_silence_len = 500,
        # adjust this per requirement
        silence_thresh = sound.dBFS-14,
        # keep the silence for 1 second, adjustable as well
        keep_silence=500,
    )
    folder_name = "audio-chunks"
    # create a directory to store the audio chunks
    if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
    whole_text = ""
    # process each chunk
    for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
        # export audio chunk and save it in
        # the `folder_name` directory.
        chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
        audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
        # recognize the chunk
        with sr.AudioFile(chunk_filename) as source:
            audio_listened = r.record(source)
            # try converting it to text
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio_listened)
            except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
                print("Error:", str(e))
            else:
                text = f"{text.capitalize()}. "
                print(chunk_filename, ":", text)
                whole_text += text
    # return the text for all chunks detected
    return whole_text

path = "Video.wav"
print("\nFull text:", get_large_audio_transcription(path))
```

I get this message:

```
Error: 
Error: 
audio-chunks\chunk3.wav : I'm on a plane in a heartbeat you let me know. 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
audio-chunks\chunk7.wav : Really why. 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
audio-chunks\chunk12.wav : So you're a one girl guy that's right right looking for it right now actually don't laugh i just got in town i got the new job trying to get this apartment. 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
audio-chunks\chunk16.wav : Yeah i could i'm working at the hospital but beautiful woman as well. 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
Error: 
audio-chunks\chunk22.wav : Video. 
Error: 
Error: 

Full text: I'm on a plane in a heartbeat you let me know. Really why. So you're a one girl guy that's right right looking for it right now actually don't laugh i just got in town i got the new job trying to get this apartment. Yeah i could i'm working at the hospital but beautiful woman as well. Video.
```

How can I fix this issue?